# How to plan Currency Symbol in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to change plan Currency in Stripe Account,Am Create plan using Currency USD But now want to change GBP Currency in plan edit details in stripe account cant find to edit currency option having to edit name and description only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, you'll need to create a new plan.
There's only a few options you can change on a plan. See here - https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_plan

Think about this -
A customer signs up to your plan at $10 / month.
You now change this to £10 / month. This is 1.4(aprox) the value (current exchange rate) The customers who signed up to the plan when it was in USD would now be out of pocket